# Transpiling a TypeScript project with ts-loader or babel-loader giving ESLint error "invalid escape" for /\p{Diacritic}/

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, webpack, babel-loader

I've got a TypeScript project set to `ES6` target and `ESNext` module (though preferably I'd like to target ES5, this is fine for now).

I'm using `ts-loader` (and tested with `babel-loader`) to transpile this into an ESM module. In both cases, the following line that uses the new "Unicode properties" syntax `\p` is throwing an ESLint error.

Here's the transpiled line:

```
d = e => e.normalize("NFKD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "").replace("ø", "o").replace("Ø", "O").replace("ð", "d").replace("Ð", "D"),
```

From the original TS:

```
export const normalize = (str: string): string => {
  // Translates the Unicode Normalization Form of the string into the Normalization Form Canonical Composition.
  // Extra consideration for the letters ø,ð, Ð, which are not included in the NFKD normalization.
  return (
    str
      .normalize("NFKD")
      .replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")
      .replace("ø", "o")
      .replace("Ø", "O")
      .replace("ð", "d")
      .replace("Ð", "D")
  );
};
```

As far as I can tell, this transpiled correctly, but ESLint is mad with:

> Parsing error: Invalid regular expression: /\p{Diacritic}/: Invalid escapeeslint

```
d = e => e.normalize("NFKD").replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, "")....
                                      ^ here
```

I believe this is correct, but perhaps I have either the wrong target somewhere in webpack, babel, or ts-loader (even though both babel and ts-loader emit the same code)?

Though I can't seem to find when Unicode properties were added, one mention online says ES2018, but others go back to 2016. Is this a target issue? Do I need a polypill here?

Or is this just an .eslintrc thing?

---

Here are my configs:

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "ES6", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "paths": {
      "@namesrhard/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts", "tests/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "jest.config.**", "webpack.config.js", "dist"]
}
```

#### webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const TerserPlugin = require("terser-webpack-plugin");

const exclude = /(node_modules|tests|dist|build|coverage.vscode)/;

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  devtool: "inline-source-map",
  // context: path.resolve(__dirname, "../"),
  entry: {
    objedi: "./src/objedi.ts",
  },
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./dist/"),
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts"],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
    minimizer: [
      new TerserPlugin({
        exclude,
      }),
    ],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            configFile: "tsconfig.dist.json",
          },
        },
        exclude,
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

#### .babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-unicode-sets-regex"]
}
```

And I've tested using both independently:

```
rm -rf dist && webpack // yarn build:webpack
```

```
babel dist --out-dir dist --extensions \".js\" --source-maps inline // yarn build:babel
```

Comment: Not my area of expertise but setting the "target" to "ES6" seems possibly a problem.

Comment: Also I can't imagine how that could work in ES5; it's part of the regular expression syntax, which is part of the language grammar; it's not something that can be solved with a library version.

Comment: Mr Crowder's recent book says ES2018.

Comment: Good start, but even changing all the targets to ES2018 still makes it mad.

Comment: Actually, to match diacritics, you can use `\p{M}`

Comment: See also [this issue on the Typescript GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32214)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhgh @Pointy that looks like it. Drat.